# Maximizing expectation integral given PDF inequality

Tags: probability, expectation, integral-inequality

I came across a paper that in the context of one of its proofs takes an upper bound on a random variable's probability distribution and turns it into a bound on its expected value.

In particular, let $X$ be a random variable with PDF $f$. The result is that if $$P(X \geq x) = \int_x^\infty f(\gamma) d\gamma \leq 2 e^{-2mx^2}$$ then $$E\left[e^{2(m-1)X^2}\right] = \int_0^\infty f(\gamma)e^{2(m-1)\gamma^2} d\gamma \leq 4m.$$

The paper proposes a proof saying that the first constraint is met with equality for $g(\gamma) = 8 m \gamma e^{-2m\gamma^2}$ and that this distribution will maximize the expected value expression. For this distribution one can compute the expected value to be $E\left[e^{2(m-1)X^2}\right] = \int_0^\infty 8 m \gamma e^{-2m\gamma^2}e^{2(m-1)\gamma^2} d\gamma = 4m$.

I believe that the result is true (I came up with a different proof) but I am confused about the validity of this argument. Why is it true that a distribution, $g$, that achieves equality in the first constraint will also maximize the expected value expression?

If it was true that for such a $g$ we knew $g(\gamma) \geq f(\gamma)$ for any $f$ satisfying the first inequality then I could see why this argument is valid. However, I don't think that's necessarily true. Consider the following counterexample. Suppose that $\int_x^1 f(\gamma) d\gamma \leq 1 - x$. Equality can be achieved for $g(\gamma) = 1$. However, $f(\gamma) =  3/2 e^{-\gamma}$ also meets the inequality and yet it is not true that $ 3/2 e^{-\gamma}  \leq 1$ for all $\gamma$.

So I am wondering if this argument is valid and if so how?

Comment: The equality is talking about the survival function $\bar{F}_X = \Pr\{X > x\}$ of a non-negative random variable, and it is related to the expectation by $\displaystyle E[X] = \int_0^{+\infty} \bar{F}_X(x) dx$. If $\bar{F}_X(x) \geq \bar{F}_Y(x)$ for every $x$, then $E[X] \geq E[Y]$. So if there is a distribution attains the equality for every $x$, then it must be the distribution that maximize the expectation in this class.

Comment: @BGM your argument shows that $E[X] \geq E[Y]$ when $X \sim g$ and $Y \sim f$ but this wasn't exactly the original question. Does this result somehow imply the original one that $E[e^{2(m-1)Y^2}] \geq E[e^{2(m-1)X^2}]$ ?

Comment: Sorry I miss that. The condition given means that the distribution that attains the equality, say $X^*$, will first order stochastic dominance the remaining distributions in this class, since it is the definition. Then for every weakly increasing function $u$, we have $E[u(X^*)] > E[u(X)]$ and this can be considered as the another definition. See, e.g. https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/economics/14-123-microeconomic-theory-iii-spring-2015/lecture-notes-and-slides/MIT14_123S15_Chap4.pdf

Comment: @BGM I dont know what you mean. Is X a distribution or a random variable? Also Im not sure of the connection between lotteries and random variables. Is there a straightforward proof of the result?

Comment: Sorry I am not sure about your doubts too. $X$ we usually called it is a random variable and it follows a certain distribution. The proof is not too complicated and listed in the quoted link above - from P.1 to P.3. I am not sure where does lottery come up.

Comment: @BGM I agree that $X$ is usually a random variable but you claim that $X*$ is a distribution that achieves equality (making it sound like $X*$ is a distribution). I'll try to take a closer look. I am having some trouble translating between the results in the link you referenced and statement I have above. I think there may be enough there to solve the stated problem but I'm not sure. If you have time and can present a simple proof using the form of the problem in the OP that would be super helpful!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that the argument from the paper is valid. Thanks to @BGM's explanation and the reference he gave I now see how to justify it. Just reposting the argument here a bit more explicitly since the notation and vocabulary from @BGM's reference are a little bit different and to me the connection wasn't obvious.

The constraint we are given is that
$$ \int_x^\infty f(\gamma) d\gamma \leq \int_x^\infty g(\gamma) d\gamma  = e^{-2mx^2} \quad \forall x>0
$$ 
and we want to show that
$$ \int_0^\infty u(\gamma) f(\gamma) d\gamma \leq \int_0^\infty u(\gamma) g(\gamma) d\gamma
$$
where $u(\gamma) = e^{2(m-1)\gamma^2}.$

Equivalently, if we assume that $X$ and $Y$ are random variables with support $(0, \infty)$ and $X$ has distribution $f$ and $Y$ has distribution $g$ we want to show $E[u(X)] \leq E[u(Y)]$.

The first inequality is equivalent to an inequality of the CDF of $X$ and $Y$, $F$ and $G$, respectively. Specifically, we have $F(x) \geq G(x)$ since 
$$
F(x) = 1 - \int_x^\infty f(\gamma) d\gamma \geq 1 - \int_x^\infty g(\gamma) d\gamma = G(x) \quad \forall x > 0.
$$

We note that because $F$ and $G$ are increasing functions with $F(0) = G(0) = 0$ and $F(x) = G(x) = 1$ as $x \to \infty$ we have $F^{-1}(p) \leq G^{-1}(p)$ and as CDFs their derivatives are the distributions, i.e. $dF/d\gamma = f(\gamma)$ and $dG/d\gamma = g(\gamma)$.

The desired result now follows from a $u$-substitution $p=F(\gamma)$ and a $u$-substition back, $p = G(\gamma)$:
$$
\int_0^\infty u(\gamma) f(\gamma) d\gamma = \int_0^1 u(\gamma) f(\gamma) \frac{dp}{f(\gamma)} = \int_0^1 u(F^{-1}(p)) dp \leq \int_0^1 u(G^{-1}(p)) dp = \int_0^\infty u(\gamma)g(\gamma) d\gamma
$$
where the inequality follows because $u$ is an increasing function.

In summary, this says that if we have an upper bound on the survival function of a random variable we can use a distribution which achieves equality with this bound to set a bound on the expected value of any increasing function of the random variable.

Comment: Nice work to clarify all the results! The conclusion you have is general enough, and you may have other chances to apply it for other problem.

Answer (score 0):

$\def\e{\mathrm{e}}\def\d{\mathrm{d}}$The argument used in the paper is indeed wrong. Here is a proof using integration by parts.

For any $f$ satisfying$$
\int_x^{+\infty} f(u) \,\d u \leqslant 2\e^{-2mx^2}, \quad \forall x > 0
$$
using Tonelli's theorem,\begin{align*}
&\mathrel{\phantom{=}}{} \int_0^{+\infty} f(u) \e^{2(m - 1)u} \,\d u = \int_0^{+\infty} f(u) \left(1 + 2(m - 1) \int_0^u \e^{2(m - 1)v} \,\d v\right) \d u \\
&= \int_0^{+\infty} f(u) \,\d u + 2(m - 1) \int_0^{+\infty} \int_0^u f(u) \e^{2(m - 1)v} \,\d v \d u\\
&= 1 + 2(m - 1) \int_0^{+\infty} \int_v^{+\infty} f(u) \e^{2(m - 1)v} \,\d v \d u\\
&= 1 + 2(m - 1) \int_0^{+\infty} \e^{2(m - 1)v} \,\d v \int_v^{+\infty} f(u) \,\d u\\
&\stackrel{(1)}{\leqslant} 1 + 2(m - 1) \int_0^{+\infty} \e^{2(m - 1)v} \,\d v \int_v^{+\infty} g(u) \,\d u\\
&= \int_0^{+\infty} g(u) \e^{2(m - 1)u} \,\d u = 4m.
\end{align*}

To achieve equality, from (1) there is$$
\int_x^{+\infty} f(u) \,\d u = \int_x^{+\infty} g(u) \,\d u, \quad \forall x > 0
$$
i.e.$$
\int_x^{+\infty} (f(u) - g(u)) \,\d u = 0, \quad \forall x > 0
$$
thus $f = g\ \text{a.e.}$

Comment: Alex Francisco, you have misunderstood a few things: 1. The counterexample is not to the original claim but rather to the claim that if $\int_x^a f(\gamma) d\gamma \leq \int_x^a g(\gamma) d\gamma$ for all $x \in (0, a)$ then $f(\gamma) \geq g(\gamma)$ for all $\gamma \in (0, a)$. Whether or not $f$ and $g$ are distributions is irrelevant

Comment: 2. The claim you proved is that if $\int_x^\infty f(\gamma) d \gamma \leq \int_x^\infty g(\gamma) d \gamma$ for all $x \in (0, \infty)$ and $\int_0^\infty f(\gamma) e^{2(m-1) \gamma^2} d\gamma = \int_0^\infty g(\gamma) e^{2(m-1) \gamma^2} d\gamma$ then $g(\gamma) = f(\gamma)$ for almost all $x$. This is not the claim asked in the OP at all.

Comment: The claim asked about in the OP is to show that if $\int_x^\infty f(\gamma) d \gamma \leq \int_x^\infty g(\gamma) d \gamma$ for all $x \in (0, \infty)$ then $\int_0^\infty f(\gamma) e^{2(m-1) \gamma^2} d\gamma \leq \int_0^\infty g(\gamma) e^{2(m-1) \gamma^2} d\gamma$

Comment: In my first comment the inequality between $f$ and $g$ should read $f(\gamma) \leq g(\gamma)$

Comment: Yes, the first constraint meaning the inequality $\int_x^\infty f(\gamma) d\gamma \leq 2 e^{-2mx^2} = \int_x^\infty g(\gamma) d\gamma$. The question is, for this $g$ and any $f$ that satisfies the inequality to prove that $\int_0^\infty f(\gamma) e^{2(m-1)\gamma^2} d\gamma \leq \int_0^\infty g(\gamma) e^{2(m-1)\gamma^2} d\gamma$

Comment: Alex, cool, cool, glad we're on the same page. My proof sets up a double integral and uses Fubini's theorem to exchange integrals. Sounds good, no rush. Curious to see if there is a different way to justify the original result.

Comment: @Homotopy Corrected now. There's probably no other way to use the given condition.

Comment: Alex, the proof of the claim in the paper looks good! I did something very similar. I will try to post it later. I don't think that last step is necessary, the chain of equalities/inequalities proves the result. (1) is justified by the condition given in the paper. I also may have a way to justify the argument in the paper, I'm still trying to work it out but will post it if it does. Hope you've enjoyed thinking about the problem!

Answer (score 0):

As requested I repost the argument here. Let $X^*$ be a continuous random variable with pdf
$$ f_{X^*}(x) = 8mxe^{-2mx^2}, m > 0$$

The support is not specified so I guess the author is only concerned about the tail behavior. Assume the support to be $[\underline{x}, +\infty)$. The survival function is given by

$$ \Pr\{X^* \geq x\} = \int^{+\infty}_x 8mue^{-2mu^2}du = 2e^{-2mx^2}, x \geq \underline{x}$$

and we can compute $\underline{x}$ anyway (not important)
$$ 2e^{-2m\underline{x}^2} = 1 \Rightarrow \underline{x} = \underline{x} = \sqrt{ \frac {\ln 2} {2m}}$$

Define

$$ \mathcal{X}=\left\{X: \Pr\{X \geq x\} \leq 2e^{-2mx^2} ~\forall  x \geq \underline{x}, m > 0, \Pr\{X \geq 0\} = 1 \right\}$$

be the collection of random variables satisfying the given inequality constraint. 
Then from the above calculation $X^* \in \mathcal{X}$ and
$$ \Pr\{X^* \geq x\} \geq \Pr\{X \geq x\} ~~ \forall x \in \mathbb{R}, X \in \mathcal{X} $$

And this is the usual definition of $X^*$ first-ordered stochastic dominate $X$ (for every $X \in \mathcal{X}$). From the link https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/economics/14-123-microeconomic-theory-iii-spring-2015/lecture-notes-and-slides/MIT14_123S15_Chap4.pdf P.1-3, it explained this term and proved that for every weakly increasing function $u$, we also have

$$ E[u(X^*)] \geq E[u(X)] ~~ \forall X \in \mathcal{X}$$

and this is another equivalent definition from above. The proof is written there and is quite clear so I do not think it is necessary to retype line by line. If there is any doubt then we can discuss afterward.

The final thing is to check the given function $h(x) = e^{2(m-1)x^2}$ is weakly increasing (on $[\underline{x}, +\infty)$)- it merely require $m > 1$.

Comment: Thanks BGM. I appreciate the effort but the result that you glossed over and just referenced the paper is really what I was looking for. I still don't think it is totally clear how to translate from one to the other. For one thing, the result you quote isn't even found in the notes explicitly! think I see how to and will try and write a post clarifying later.

Comment: I added an answer to my post that uses the ideas in the paper you reference to solve our problem without introducing new notation or vocabulary.